# GWT SuggestBox - how to force selection of n'th suggestion from popup

Tags: java, gwt

I have a SuggestBox with an oracle full of geocoded addresses.  I want to enter a specific default text (actually an initial address from the URL parameter) with setValue() or setText() and then trigger the SuggestBox to pick the first value from the suggestion oracle popup matching that text.  Any ideas please?

I am able to set the text and then trigger showSuggestionList() but I don't know how to then simulate the user clicking on the top suggestion.  Or maybe there is a more direct approach without physically showing the popup.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the oracle, you just fire a valuechange event.

Comment: I don't know the value - I want to read the top value from the oracle/suggestion popup and trigger a value change event for that value